# Product of Lexical Specification

Tags: regular-expressions

I have a problem that asks me to consider the string abbbaacc. I'm supposed to figure out which of the following lexical specification produces the tokenization ab/bb/a/acc.

The options are:

```
A.
    a(b+c)*
    b+

B.
    ab 
    b+
    ac*

C.
    c* 
    b+
    ab
    ac*

D.
    b+ 
    ab*
    ac*
```

I just learned about REGEX, and I'm not sure about this, but to solve this problem would I just be trying see which options can make ab/bb/a/acc?

If that's correct, then would the answer be all four of them?

Since all four of them can match to ab/bb/a/acc:

```
A.
     a(b+c)* -> a, ab, acc 
     b+ -> bb
B. 
     ab -> ab
     b+ -> bb
     ac* -> a, acc
C.
     c* -> 
     b+ -> bb
     ab -> ab
     ac* -> a, acc
D. 
     b+ -> bb
     ab* -> a, ab
     ac* -> a, acc
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

Comment: How does one tokenize an input given a lexical specification? Using [maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) or using some other rule? Please include this information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information here to answer the question, but I can prove a pretty good guess based on how tokenizers are typically implemented.  Generally the tokenizer will run through the list of patterns, trying each one I sequence.  If one of them matches it takes the longest possible match as a token, then starts over at the top of the list.  I surmise this is the implicit background for the question.

So, for instance, if you have `abbbaacc` and the rules `a(b|c)*` and `b+` in that order, then you'd tokenize that as `abbb/a/acc`.